# The Basis for Product Toplogy

Tags: general-topology

Hi i am reading Topology by Munkres and having 3 doubts under the section The product Topology at page no 86. There it is written that

> The union of the two rectangles pictured in Figure is not a product of two sets so it cannot belong to $\mathcal{B}$ however it is open in $X\times Y$ .

My doubts are as following:

1. Why is it that the union of two rectangles is not a product of two sets?
   I think what i am asking is why is this $(U_1\times V_1)\ \cup (U_2\times V_2) = (U_1\ \cup U_2)\times (V_1\ \cup V_2)$ not true?
2. How is that union  open in $X\times Y$ ?
3. Why is this $(U_1\times V_1)\ \cap (U_2\times V_2) = (U_1\cap U_2)\times (V_1\cap V_2)$ true? Is there a rule that applies to intersection but not to union?Or rather which law(like De Morgan's law) are we using?

For reference i am attaching the screenshot where i have highlighted the part.

[image: Screenshot 1][image: Screenshot 2]

Comment: that union is open in $X\times Y$ because it is a union of basis elements

Comment: If you take an $x$-coord "away" from the overlap and do the same for $y$, you can make a point that is not in the shaded bit.

Comment: As your question has nothing to do with cross-product, algebraic topology or manifolds, I removed these tags from your question, which is only related to basic general-topology

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer to all the questions are as follows:

1. [Proof of this is here](https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Cartesian_Product_Distributes_over_Union)
2. Because it is the union of two of its basis element. As said by @J.W.Tanner
3. [Proof of this is here](https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Cartesian_Product_of_Intersections)

Answer (score 2):

1. If you pick an element $u\in U_1\setminus U_2$ and $v\in V_2\setminus V_1$, it is clear that $(u,v)$ is in $(U_1\cup U_2)\times(V_1\cup V_2)$ but not in $(U_1\times V_1)\cup(U_2\times V_2)$.
2. Any union of sets of the basis of a topology is an open set, so this is a direct consequence of the definition of product topology.
3. A point $(u,v)$ is in $(U_1\times V_1)\ \cap (U_2\times V_2)$ iff it is in $U_1\times V_1$ and in $U_2\times V_2$, that is, if $u$ is in $U_1$ and in $U_2$ and $v$ is in $V_1$ and $V_2$. This is equivalent to saying that $u\in U_1\cap U_2$ and $v\in V_1\cap V_2$, which means that $(u,v)$ is in $(U_1\cap U_2)\times (V_1\cap V_2)$.

You can deduce all these laws regarding products, unions and intersections using just the definitions of these concepts and logic. The only logic laws that have been implicitly used in this reasoning are associativity and commutativity of conjunctions.

Comment: What does $U_1\setminus U_2$ in your notation mean? Is it or , and?

Comment: It is the standard notation for difference of sets, $x$ is an element of $X\setminus Y$ when it is an element of $X$ but not an element of $Y$.

Comment: Ok i have seen $X-Y$ or $X\sim Y$ for difference of sets in textbooks.

Comment: Actually I prefer the notation $X-Y$ XD but I tend to use the other one in short answers like this one because it´s the most usual notation in the books I´ve read

Comment: @JasonLiam: $X\setminus Y$ is now the standard notation; one still sees $X-Y$, especially in elementary textbooks, but it’s a bit old-fashioned, and $X\sim Y$ is *very* old-fashioned.